# Does kinking the wire of a psu affect power ouput?

Tags: power-supply

Just like the title says; does kinking the cable from a psu(2.5A 5v) to the socket affect the noticeable peformance of a psu? It is just slightly kinked at multiple places.

Comment: According to my 4-yr old daughter, absolutely yes. This is how she tricks me by bending the power cable going into my laptop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  Electricity isn't like water, it doesn't mind going round corners (at least not on that scale), and a piece of copper cable can't collapse and close off the way a hosepipe can.

Kinking a cable still isn't a great idea though.  Bends over sharp edges, or repeatedly bending and straightening a cable can damage the insulation.  Then you can get an electric shock, or it can start a fire.

Answer (score 0):

Not only can it damage the insulation but the wires inside can crack and break from the bending back and forth.  Less wires means less ability to handle current.  They could heat up more and possibly cause a fire depending on the amount of damage.